# Create a procedure in DB2

Tags: shell, db2, procedure

I created a simple procedure using DB2 in .sql file and executed the script with Shell (Unix). I got an error : SQLSTATE 42601.

```
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_SAMPLE1()
BEGIN
update EMP set ENAME='ALLAIN' where EMPNO=7789
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "IN'
where EMPNO=7789".  Expected tokens may include:  "<psm_semicolon>".  LINE
NUMBER=3.  SQLSTATE=42601
```

There is the procedure :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_SAMPLE1()
BEGIN
update EMP set ENAME='ALLAIN' where EMPNO=7789;
END
/
```

Comment: Please paste the UNIX commad you used. What was the specified statement terminator? You would need to use "/".

Comment: db2 -tvsf proc_file.sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is contained in a file you need to change the batch terminator.  Since the SP lines end with `;` the batch ends with `/`, you need to specify this on the command line.

eg

```
db2 -td/ -f <your file>.sql
```

> I like to use # since it does not mess with unix shells like `/` will.  Here replace your last character with `#` in the file and use `-td#`

Comment: How does a `/` mess with unix shells (any more than `#`) ?

Comment: @IanBjorhovde - because / is used as an escape character in some contexts

Comment: Don't you mean ` \ `?

Comment: @IanBjorhovde - I've seen both used as escape characters in different contexts.

Comment: You've seen `/` used as an escape in a UNIX *shell*?

Comment: @IanBjorhovde sure -- as a marker in regex for example.

Answer (score 0):

I added '--#SET TERMINATOR /' before the procedure creation and the problem is solved.

```
--#SET TERMINATOR /
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_SAMPLE1()
BEGIN
update EMP set ENAME='ALLAIN' where EMPNO=7789;
END
/
```

Comment: This works, but keep in mind only the DB2 Command Line Processor (CLP) will interpret `--#SET TERMINATOR x`.